# Searching for Nodes with Specific Text using the Prototype Javascript Framework

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, css-selectors

Does the Prototype Javascript library have a selector that's equivalent to jQuery's [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)?  If not, what would what be "The Prototype Way" to selector/filter-down a list of elements that contains a particular string.

For example, using the following

```
$$('#some_div dd a')
```

I may get back an array of 50 or so links.  I **only** want the links that contain the work 'home'.  In jQuery I'd do this

```
jQuery("#some_div dd a:contains('home')");
```

Is it possible to do something similar using Prototype?  If not, is there an elegant way to filter out the array of 50 elements that gets returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (non-Sizzle) answer I've been able to find so is to filter things out with the `findAll` method.

```
$$(selector).findAll(function(e){ return e.innerHTML.indexOf(label) != -1;})
```

Comment: thanks Alan, worked first time.  Perfect for highlighting values in an adminhtml grid. e.g. insert a new skin_js via layout with the following
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
   $$('.status').findAll(function(e){
       if(e.innerHTML.indexOf('Received, Pending Review') != -1){
           e.addClassName('urgent');
       }
   });
});
  Depends on using the 'column_css_class' => 'status' parameter of addColumn();

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the article on the Sizzle intergreation.

http://prototypejs.org/2010/4/5/prototype-1-7-rc1-sizzle-layout-dimensions-api-event-delegation-and-more

This should help you.

Comment: +1 for useful information, and that looks pretty sweet. However, if I could control what version of prototype I was using on this project, I'd pick jQuery ;)

Comment: I Would then suggest that you incorperate SizzleJS inside your application as a library and not part of prototype. such things as `$$(Sizzle('#divid:contains(\'hello world\')'))` this is the best i got :)

Comment: Simple (doesn't exclude classnames or tags, but still might be helpful) contain:  `$$('#some_div dd a').each(function(s) {        if( s.innerHTML.indexOf('home') >= 0 ) {  /* do something */  } });`